# Mean/median/mode from complex table in lua

Tags: lua, statistics, mean, lua-table

Thank you for all the support with lua, I'm very new and my application is working nicely so far.

I've made an app that will take in a few thousand numbers for different items. I'm trying to find the Mean/Media/Mode for each item, I've been able to do this for a single item, but not for all items.

Here is my table structure:

```
for i = 0, 1500 do
            local e = {}
            e.seller,
            e.buyer,
            e.itemName,
            e.soldAmount = GetSoldAmount(FromMember(i))
       table.insert(allSalesTempTable, e)
end
```

Table output format

```
  [1] = 
                {
                    ["itemName"] = [[Salad]]
                    ["buyer"] = [[@Mike]],
                    ["eventType"] = 15,
                    ["soldAmount"] = 150,
                    ["seller"] = [[@Sarah]],
                },
  [2] =
                {
                    ["itemName"] = [Pizza]
                    ["buyer"] = [[@James]],
                    ["eventType"] = 15,
                    ["soldAmount"] = 150,
                    ["seller"] = [[@Sarah]],
                },
  [3] =
                {
                    ["itemName"] = [Salad]
                    ["buyer"] = [[@Frank]],
                    ["eventType"] = 15,
                    ["soldAmount"] = 75,
                    ["seller"] = [[@Sarah]],
                },
  [4] ...

 },
```

Then I'm trying to send the table/array to this mean function

```
stats={}

-- Get the mean value of a table
    function stats.mean( t )
        local sum = 0
        local count= 0
        local tempTbl = {}

(This is completely  not going to work, but its what I'm trying so far) 
    for k,v in pairs(t) do tempTbl[k] = v
        if v.itemName == tempTbl.itemName then
            sum = sum + v.soldAmount
            count = count + 1
        end
    end

    return (sum / count)
end
```

--- To get the function started
    stats.mean(e)

Here is where I'm getting fuzzy, Not sure if I can add the MEAN while collecting the data into the first temp table, or if it needs to be re-calculated after I have all the data?
 If it needs to be done after, then my stats.mean(e) needs a way to insert it?

I'm trying to get this output:

```
  [1] = 
                {
                    ["itemName"] = [[Salad]]
                    ["buyer"] = [[@Mike]],
                    ["eventType"] = 15,
                    ["soldAmount"] = 150,
                    ["seller"] = [[@Sarah]],
                    ["mean"] = 112.5   - New  Insert somehow
                },
  [2] =
                {
                    ["itemName"] = [Pizza]
                    ["buyer"] = [[@James]],
                    ["eventType"] = 15,
                    ["soldAmount"] = 150,
                    ["seller"] = [[@Sarah]],
                    ["mean"] = 150   - New  Insert somehow
                },
  [3] =
                {
                    ["itemName"] = [Salad]
                    ["buyer"] = [[@Frank]],
                    ["eventType"] = 15,
                    ["soldAmount"] = 75,
                    ["seller"] = [[@Sarah]],
                    ["mean"] = 112.5   - New  Insert somehow
                },
  [4] ...

 },
```

I've been working on this problem for a few days, After I see how to adjust my format for the mean and insert into the existing table I'll be able to figure out mean/min/max/median/mode easy enough.

Comment: [lua](https://github.com/LuaDist/lua) ~= [LUA](https://github.com/mniip/LUA)

Comment: Thanks hj, 
I'm not quite sure on this still, still attempting.

Comment: Still attempting this. If anyone has any direction I'd be very appreciative